# Run tasks on different hosts within an imported task

Tags: ansible

The calling playbook has:

```
- hosts: ssh_servers
  tasks:
  - import_tasks: create_files.yml
```

Then, in create_files.yml, I'd like to run some tasks on hosts *other* than ssh_servers, such as:

```
- Hosts: other_servers
  tasks:
  - file:
```

I get: ERROR! conflicting action statements: hosts, tasks .

Is this because I'm trying to run against hosts that were never included in the calling task ?
Is there a way to accomplish this other than in the calling playbook have:

```
- hosts: 
   - ssh_servers
   - other_servers
  tasks:
  - import_tasks: create_files.yml
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's not possible to nest [plays](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks.html#working-with-playbooks). What is the use-case? Make it [mre].

Comment: I was afraid that was true, I figured too much was being asked from Ansible at that point. When running running this as its own playbooks things worked, that's when I became suspicious.

Comment: [A play is a mapping of hosts to tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-language-example). The recursion would make the complexity exponential.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this because I'm trying to run against hosts that were never included in the calling task ? Is there a way to accomplish this other than in the calling playbook

I believe the answer is yes, although it'll be weird and could cause subsequent folks who interact with your playbook some confusion

given a hypothetical `create_files.yml` of:

```yaml
- name: create /tmp/hello_world on hosts "not_known_at_launch_time"
  file:
    path: /tmp/hello_world
    state: present
  delegate_to: '{{ item }}'
  with_items: '{{ groups["not_known_at_launch_time"] }}'
```

then the glue needed to bridge them together is [the dynamic creation of a group](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html) and that [`delegate_to:` keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-tasks)

```yaml
- hosts: ssh_hosts
  tasks:
  - add_host:
      groups: not_known_at_launch_time
      name: secret-host-0
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.1  # or whatever
      # ... other hostvars here ...
  - include_tasks: create_files.yml
```

it may be possible to combine those inside `create_files.yml`, via some shared `vars:` that say which host-and-ip should be added to the magic group name, which also has the benefit of keeping the magic group name localized to the file that consumes it.

**BE AWARE**, I did actually test this, but not extensively, so there may be some weird things such as the need to `run_once: yes` on them to keep the tasks from being run `groups.ssh_hosts|length` times or similar stuff

As Vladimir correctly pointed out, what you *actually* want to happen is to make that relationship formal:

```yaml
- hosts: ssh_hosts
  tasks:
  ... whatever tasks you had before
  - add_host: ... as before ...

- hosts: anonymous_group_name_goes_here
  tasks:
  - include_tasks: create_files.yml

- hosts: ssh_hosts
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: and now you are back to the ssh_hosts to pick up what they were supposed to be doing when you stopped to post on SO
```

Comment: Thank you, This makes sense. I agree that this is generally not a good idea and i'd rather try out other solutions for this issue that are less risky. This was more of a desperation try on my end, and I should probably avoid that.